# enable on Wednesday /diasable Thursday from 6a to 6a

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm looking for code to make a textbox visible and a subform disabled between Wednesday 6A and Thursday at 6a.

Comment: Closed, but you got the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be:

```vb
Dim IsWednesday As Boolean

IsWednesday = CBool(Weekday(DateAdd("h", -6, Now)) = vbWednesday)

Me!YourTextbox.Visible = IsWednesday
Me!YourSubformControl.Enabled = Not IsWednesday
```